# Step Functions Versions & Alias with Blue Green Deployment

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

Trying to use the new Versioning and Alias for Step Functions via CDK.

Example from Github Issue on CDK:

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as sfn from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-stepfunctions';

/**
 * Example CDK stack demonstrating how to achieve gradual deployments
 * for Step Functions using versions and aliases.
 */
export class VersioningCdkExampleStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // StateMachine
    const stateMachine = new sfn.StateMachine(this, 'myStateMachine', {
      definition: new sfn.Pass(this, 'DefineRepositories', { result: sfn.Result.fromString("version 1") })
    });

    // Version that always points to the latest revision by using `stateMachineRevisionId`
    const version = new sfn.CfnStateMachineVersion(this, 'Version', {
      stateMachineArn: stateMachine.stateMachineArn,
      stateMachineRevisionId: stateMachine.stateMachineRevisionId,
    });

    // When the state machine changes, the CFN does an update replacement of 'Version'
    // To prevent distruption to callers of the previous version, we need to keep it.
    version.applyRemovalPolicy(cdk.RemovalPolicy.RETAIN);

    // Alias that gradually shifts 10% of traffic to the new version every minute
    const alias = new sfn.CfnStateMachineAlias(this, 'preProd', {
  routingConfiguration: [{
    stateMachineVersionArn: version.ref,
    weight: 100,
  }],
    })
  }
}
```

Ideally I would like to create a Prod Alias. I would deploy the above CDK stack, perform tests against the State Machine and then update the Prod Alias to this new version.

Is it possible to manage this alias via the same stack?
Or is it possible to pass the version references to a new stack that manages the Prod Alias?

Answer (score 0):

The CDK/CloudFormation [gradual deployment options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/version-rolling-deployment.html) for aliases shift traffic between two versions of a State Machine in the same environment.  For instance, you can set a [deploymentPreference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stepfunctions-statemachinealias-deploymentpreference.html) to shift an additional 10% of traffic to a new version every minute.  If the configured alarm is trigered, the deployment will stop and roll back to the previous version.  In the happy case, the deployment ends 10 minutes later when 100% of alias executions are routed to the new version:

```js
const alias = new sfn.CfnStateMachineAlias(this, 'myAlias', {
  deploymentPreference: {
      type: "LINEAR",
      interval: 1,
      percentage: 10,
      alarms: [alarm.alarmName],
      stateMachineVersionArn: version.ref
    }
})
```

(Note that the OP's last code comment is incorrect.  You won't get a gradual deployment using `routingConfiguration`.  The defined [routingConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stepfunctions-statemachinealias-routingconfigurationversion.html) shifts 100% of traffic immediately to the new version.  As an aside, you could add a second version to the `routingConfiguration` array, say with weights of 50% each, to implement A/B testing.)

That being said, your use case is different.  Instead of gradually moving production traffic between two versions, it appears you want to run tests on the new version *before* deploying it to production.  This is a valid use case for aliases.  The [aws-stepfunctions-examples](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-stepfunctions-examples/blob/main/gradual-deploy/sfndeploy.py) repo has a python script that does just that with SDK calls.  However, getting that SDK logic to work with your CDK app would be tricky.

It seems to me you could achieve your goal much more easily with a CDK deployment [pipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html), instead of aliases.  Your pipeline would first deploy the stack to a staging environment.  Your tests run against the new state machine version in the staging environment.  If the test suite passes, the pipeline deploys the stack with the new version to the production environment.

The AWS [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/deploying-state-machines-incrementally-with-versions-and-aliases-in-aws-step-functions/) about aliases says the following about Blue/Green deployments:

> As a rule, you should deploy the blue version in production, while testing the newer green version in a separate environment. Once the green version is validated, use it in production (it becomes the new blue version).

A CDK pipeline does exactly this.  Optionally combine the pipeline approach (first test in a separate env) and alias approach (gradual deployment in prod).